# Print last "window" with sed

Tags: sed

I have a log to process that's roughly structured like this:

```
...
...
sentinel
marker
...
marker
...
sentinel
marker
...
```

I want everything between a `marker` and the following `sentinel`, and I want the last such "window." The following works ok:

```
sed -e "1{h;d} ; 2,109{H;d} ; 110{H;g} ; /sentinel/h ; \${g;q} ; N ; D" file.log
```

Here, 110 is a rough (but consistent within a couple lines) estimate of the space between `marker`s for *this* log, but I'd have to recompute this estimate for other logs, which is annoying.

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to achieve this with `sed`, i.e. to automatically return the last window between `marker` and `sentinel` (I'll also accept an answer that demonstrates why you *can't* do this in `sed`).

Thanks.

P.S. I know that could do this in any number of languages, but I'd like to exercise the `sed` muscles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/marker/,/sentinel/{/marker/h;//!H};$!d;x' file
```

Stash lines between `marker` and `sentinel` in the hold space (overwriting old with new) and at the end of the file print whatever is left in the hold space.

EDIT:

The solution above caters for `marker` and `sentinel` pairs. If the either of those is likely to be missing then use:

```
 sed '/marker/,/sentinel/H;$!d;x;s/.*\(marker.*sentinel\).*/\1/p;d' file
```

This saves all `marker/sentinel` pairs in the hold space and the at end of the file removes all but the last complete pair.

Comment: perfect, just replacing the last `;` (after `!d`) by a new line and adding a `;` (or new line) before `}` in case of POSIX version (aka non GNU sed)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I've tried a few things like this. What happens is that `/marker/,/sentinel/` also matches everything between `marker` and the end of the file, so it always retrieves the last part of the file, regardless if there is a `sentinel` there.

Comment: @potong Yes! That worked. I knew your first one had to be close, and I figured an `s` would feature in there somewhere, I just didn't think to do it on all the matches concatenated together.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there are no blank lines in the file, you could do:

```
sed -e '/^marker$/i\
\
' -e '/^sentinel$/a\
\
' input | awk '/sentinel/{l=$0}END{print l}' RS=
```

(Not sure I'd call that elegant: basically you are inserting blank lines between the records and letting awk's RS to the hard work.  If you cannot guarantee that there are no blank lines, pre/post process the data to ensure that:

```
sed 's/^/x/' input | sed -e '/^xmarker$/i\
\
' -e '/^sentinel$/a\
\
' | awk '/sentinel/{l=$0}END{print l}' RS= | sed 's/^x//'
```

(Of course, you could avoid the extra sed by wrapping them into the existing sed and the awk, but the idea is (I think) clearer this way.)